# RibbonComboBox doesn't update SelectedValue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I’ve got a ribbon combobox (MS Ribbon OpenSource project, .Net 4.0) which is data bound to a property of my viewmodel like this:

*XAML*:

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox SelectionBoxWidth="130" Margin="3,0">
  <ribbon:RibbonGallery 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel},  
    Path=Document, Converter={StaticResource DocumentToDocumentNameConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
      <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, 
        Path=Documents, Converter={StaticResource DocumentToDocumentNamesConverter}}">
      </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
  </ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```

*ViewModel*:

```
public ViewModel { 

    #region Fields
    private TestDocument _Document;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public TestDocument Document
    {
        get 
        {
            return ModelClass.SelectedDocument; 
        }
        set 
        {
            if (value != null && value != _Document)
            {
                _Document = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Document");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

That works good, if I select another value in the ComboBox the converter is entered and the value 
shown.

But if I set the property in the ViewModel like this

```
Document = new TestDocument("DocumentName");
```

the ComboBox doesn't show the name as selected.

Do you have any suggestions? I've even tried to bind SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue but this doesn't fixed the problem. Have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `SelectedItem` / Value is not part of the `ItemSource` of `RibbonComboBox`. So it does not have any effect when being set.

What you need is to first add the new item to the `ObservableCollection<TestDocument> Documents` and then set the `Document`.

something like:

```
Documents.Add(new TestDocument("DocumentName"));
Document = Documents[Documents.Count - 1];
```

or

```
var newDocument = new TestDocument("DocumentName");
Documents.Add(newDocument);
Document = newDocument;
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you, I knew that I've forgotten something.